# Accessibility Rotor changed behavior under iOS 16

Tags: swift, swiftui, accessibility, rotor

)

I'm building an app for a community of blind people. For app navigation the accessibility rotor is a very important feature. It's used for easy navigating through links. Since iOS 16 the rotor doesn't show any links in my app.
Are there any options to restore the iOS 15.7 behavior?

The code for display the links is very simple:
item.link contains a string like "https:stackoverflow.com", nothing special...

```
 ScrollView{

                Text(item.title)
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .padding()
                BigDivider()
               
                
                    
                Text(.init(item.textBody))
                    .font(.body)
                    .padding()
                    .onTapGesture {
                        isLinkClickedForDialog = false
                        showingConfirmationDialog = true   
            }
               
                if item.mediaLink != "." {
                Text(item.link)
                    .padding(.top)
                    .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                    .font(.caption2)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        isLinkClickedForDialog = true
                        showingConfirmationDialog = true
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Where do you set the accessibility rotor ?

Comment: Actually I don't set the rotor in my app. It worked under iOS 15.7 with the standard settings in settings - accessibility - rotor

Answer (score -1):

Do you need to set the accessibility trait of the text to be link?

I would not assume the OS could figure out that something with

Comment: I removed all other traits and set .isLink. The accessibility inspector recognizes a link...